# Does It Has any effect on performance to change functions.php to functions.php.inc

Tags: php, performance

I have stored all my necessary functions to a file `functions.php.inc` and I use this at the top of each page like this

```
require_once("functions.php.inc");
```

I want to know that Is there any effect on performance to have this name. If I change the `functions.php.inc` to `functions.php` will it give better performance or there is no any difference.

Comment: It really shouldn't, but the most reliable answer is available to you already if you just benchmark.

Comment: watch out, if your webserver is configured to only parse files with the `.php` extension as PHP, one could open the `.php.inc` file in a browser directly and download the file's contents instead of executing the file. Very unsafe.

Comment: Only files intended for http access should be stored within the document root, so unless Munib is making his functions publicly available it shouldn't matter what file extensions he uses.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the `.inc` warning given in comments, there should be no performance impact (extra 4 characters comparison, negligible ; the file system also is very comfortable with having to deal with a 13 or 17 chars file name).

Also, in recent versions of PHP, the APC cache is included (default), meaning that there is no extra parsing of the file that `require` that `inc` file (just the first time it is accessed). Then APC checks the file status (from file system) to detect a change when it is accessed again, from further requests.